# asp.net webforms scaffolding with EF Code first from database filter records

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, scaffolding, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am using EF Code First from Database approach and created the CRUD operations in an asp.net web application. Now I want to filter some records throughout the application.

I have Client and Product classes

Client:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        Product = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(5000)]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Product{ get; set; }
```

Product:

```
public partial class Product
{
   public Product()
   {

   }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
```

What I want is to get the products and Clients having Status = "Active"

I dont want to do it manually on each page but rather define on the class level so that could be done automatically specially on the Insert and Edit.aspx auto generated dynamic pages where Formviews are used. Kindly suggest the possible way.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working in my project like this: this allows you add you own filter method or just add the FilterByAttribute specifying what column to filter by and what value  to filter on. This works by checking for the existance of the getMethod where the name is like GetTableName and is checked for on each table. you will need to substiture the MetaModel with AdvancedMetaModel in your Global.asax file.

hope this helps.

```
    public class AdvancedMetaModel : MetaModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="provider">The provider.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override MetaTable CreateTable(TableProvider provider)
    {
        return new AdvancedMetaTable(this, provider);
    }
}

public class AdvancedMetaTable : MetaTable
{
    private SecureMetaModel SecureModel { get { return (SecureMetaModel)this.Model; } }

    public String GetMethodName { get; set; }

    private MethodInfo CreateQueryMethod { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AdvancedMetaTable"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="metaModel">The meta model.</param>
    /// <param name="tableProvider">The table provider.</param>
    public AdvancedMetaTable(MetaModel metaModel, TableProvider tableProvider) :
        base(metaModel, tableProvider)
    {
        // set the Get Method Name
        var context = base.CreateContext();
        var getMethodName = DefaultGetMethodName;
        if (context != null && context.HasMethod(DefaultGetMethodName))
        {
            GetMethodName = getMethodName;
            this.CreateQueryMethod = this.DataContextType.GetMethod(GetMethodName);
        }
        else
            GetMethodName = String.Empty;

    }

    internal String DefaultGetMethodName
    {
        get { return String.Format("Get{0}", DataContextPropertyName); }
    }

    public override IQueryable GetQuery(object context)
    {
        var filterByAttribute = this.GetAttribute<FilterByAttribute>();

        if (this.CreateQueryMethod != null)
        {
            if (context == null)
                context = this.CreateContext();
            //this.Provider.GetQuery(context);
            var query = (IQueryable)this.CreateQueryMethod.Invoke(context, null);

            if (this.SortColumn != null)
                return query.GetQueryOrdered((MetaTable)this);
            else
                return query;
        }
        else if (filterByAttribute != null)
        {
            MetaColumn filterByColumn = this.GetColumn(filterByAttribute.ColumnName);
            var query = base.GetQuery(context).GetQueryFilteredByColumn(filterByColumn, filterByAttribute.ValueWhenTrue);
            return query;
        }
        else
        {
            var query = base.GetQuery(context);
            return query;
        }
    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
```

public class FilterByAttribute : Attribute
{
    // this property is required to work with "AllowMultiple = true" ref David Ebbo
    // As implemented, this identifier is merely the Type of the attribute. However, 
    // it is intended that the unique identifier be used to identify two 
    // attributes of the same type.
    public override object TypeId { get { return this; } }

```
public String ColumnName { get; set; }

public Object ValueWhenTrue { get; set; }

public FilterByAttribute(String columnName, Object valueWhenTrue)
{
    ColumnName = columnName;
    ValueWhenTrue = valueWhenTrue;
}
```

Comment: Note there are some missing extension methods that would just clutter this up if you want them please message me directly.

Answer (score 0):

Her is an example of a custom get method

public IQueryable GetStations()
{
    var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    var stations = this.Stations.Where(s => s.Active);

```
if (!context.User.IsInRole("Acctg") && !context.User.IsInRole("Execs"))
{
    var user = MembershipHelpers.GetUser();
    var stationIds = user.Stations.Select(s => s.Id).Distinct().ToList();
    stations = stations.Where(s => stationIds.Contains(s.Id));
}

return stations;
```

}